80s-style music video/movie clip with sci-fi themes, possibly inspired by Batman (1989), Mad Max and others
This is a question I saw on Reddit's "Tip of My Tongue" subreddit here, asked by a now-deleted user in March of 2022:

So I remember this clip from a music video or movie airing on MTV sometime during the 2010s. it looked as if it was made in the 80s (early 90s at the latest), it had these two women running (assumably from something) across a railed walkway in a dark, dingy industrial building or warehouse with chains dangling from the ceiling and giant vats of some murky green liquid.
The women were both blonde with big 80s style haircuts and leather/post apoc’ gear. They run past one of the vats which has a large glass window before getting jump scared by a figure from inside the vat banging against the window.
I can't remember whether the figure in the vat was a zombie or a mutant was or just a regular person but I remember them being covered in tubes/breathing apparatus.

After a lot of googling for things like "80s music video sci-fi", I'm accepting defeat and coming here to ask if any of you recognise the video.
Two possible influences jumped out at me:

"in a dark, dingy industrial building or warehouse with chains dangling from the ceiling and giant vats of some murky green liquid." - This sounds very much like the Axis Chemicals factory in Tim Burton's Batman.

"big 80s style haircuts and leather/post apoc(alyptic) gear" - This sounds like something inspired by one of the first three Mad Max films.


Sadly, the possible zombies-with-tubes I have no idea about!
The closest video I could find was This Corrosion by Sisters of Mercy:

It looks post-apocalyptic.
There are some walkways that look industrial.
There's a woman with a big 1980s hairstyle.
0:59 has someone looking out of a barrel that might have been the "vat".

But the two characters in the video (one man, one woman) aren't running to escape from anything, in fact there's no sense of urgency at all! They just stroll around and play their instruments.
(It's an excellent video, at least in my opinion. But I don't think it's the one!)
Does anyone recognise this video/scene? And do they know which science-fiction/horror IP might have inspired the possible-zombie-with-tubes in the vat?

Has the poster ruled out the one that you found? It's a bit pointless us looking if they just turn around and say "Oh, that's it. I must have gotten mixed up"

@Valorum The original poster deleted their Reddit account at some point, so I can't contact them and they won't get notifications in the thread. And I'm not really asking on their behalf, but on mine - after reading the description, I want to see this video!
